# Passing dictionary as an input parameter to a function global/local variable issue

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi can anyone clarify this issue for me. Here is a sample of the code:

---

```
def test1(d1):
    d1_adj = d1.copy()
    d1_adj.get(0)[0] *= 10
    return d1_adj

d1 = {0: [10, 10]}
d1_adj = test1(d1)
print d1
{0: [100, 10]}
```

---

Why does d1 dictionary get updated and how can I come across this issue if I want to preserve that values of the original input dictionary and only update the values of the one that has been copied

Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because d.copy() is shallow copy. You need deep copy to accomplish this.

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

Then

```
d1_adj = deepcopy(d1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should read more about shallow copy and deep copy

Answer (score 3):

`copy` does a shallow copy, and not a deep copy, as you intended to do. Consequently, it does not create a copy of the entire list at key 0, and modifies the original list.

You may perform a manual deep copy of the values within the dictionary by traversing it once. Or better still, unless there are any requirements against using it, you may utilize `copy` module to [perform deep copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)(i.e. `copy.deepcopy`) operation. All you need to do is to update your test1 function as follows.

```
from copy import deepcopy

def test1(d1):
    d1_adj = deepcopy(d1)
    d1_adj.get(0)[0] *= 10
    return d1_adj
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! That was really helpful. Guess I should read more about deep copy and shallow copy

Comment: btw...the reason the original value was updated: did it happen cause the value of the key was a list?

Comment: @BogdanOsyka You may read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy). The differences between shallow and deep copy are highlighted in the bulleted points.